# Stylus Lookup for hash name

Tags: css, hash, lookup, stylus, for-in-loop

Is there a way to use Stylus `lookup` function for applying hashes inside for-in loop?

```
$badge-photo-S   = {
  size: 36px
  font-size: 16px
} 
$badge-photo-XS  = {
  size: 32px
  font-size: 13px
}
.s-badge
  &-photo
    for each in S XS
      &--{each}
        {lookup('$badge-photo-'+each)}
```

It should yields to:

```
.s-badge-photo--S {
  width: 36px
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 16px;
} 

.s-badge-photo--XS {
  width: 32px
  height: 32px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

But it provides an empty output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the result of `lookup` to a variable and then use it inside `{}`:

```
$badge-photo-S   = {
  size: 36px
  font-size: 16px
} 
$badge-photo-XS  = {
  size: 32px
  font-size: 13px
}
.s-badge
  &-photo
    for each in S XS
      &--{each}
        hash = lookup('$badge-photo-'+each)
        {hash}
```